# Solving a complex function in two parametres within a range

Tags: equation-solving, complex

Define:

```
YH[beta_, alpha_, Y4_] := - 173  Cos[beta] * Sin[alpha] + (2 Y4* Cos[alpha])
g[beta_, alpha_, yy_, zz_, jj_] := -Sin[alpha]  (yy + jj) + Cos[alpha]  zz

r[ms_] := (750^2)/(4.*ms^2)
k[ms_] := (-1/4)*(Log[( 1 + Sqrt[1 - r[ms]^-1])/(1 - Sqrt[1 - r[ms]^-1]) ] - (I* Pi))^2
AS[ms_] := -((r[ms]) - k[ms])/(r[ms])^2

rt := (750^2)/(4.* 173^2)
kt := (-1/ 4)*(Log[( 1 + Sqrt[1 - rt^-1])/(1 - Sqrt[1 - rt^-1]) ] - (I*Pi))^2
At := 2* (rt + ((rt - 1)*kt))/(rt)^2
```

Now my function is:

```
sigma[ms_, beta_, alpha_, Y4_, yy_, zz_, jj_] := 1/(256*Pi)* Abs[(1/2) YH[beta, alpha, Y4] * At +  3/(2 ms^2)  *AS[ms]* g[beta, alpha, yy, zz,jj]]^2 *(10)
```

I want to solve `sigma[ms, ArcTan[0.9], ArcTan[0.1], -2.0, 10, zz, 10]` for ms and zz to satisfy

`cm := 0 <= sigma[ms, ArcTan[0.9], ArcTan[0.1], -2.0, 10, zz, 10] <= 10`

The first command I can is `Reduce`, I tried:

`reg:= Reduce[cm, {ms, zz}]`

but `Reduce` here take too much time in Running and stuck, is there any thing can make Reduce more quicker and get out the solution ? or can I use other powerful command ?

**Edit**

As the discussion in this post, I learnt that one can avoid using `Reduce` for complicated function, and can know the values of the parameters which satisfy the function regions as in @Marius Ladegård Meyer answer. Now come to my `sigma`, for instance if I require `1 <= sigma[300, ArcTan[s], ArcTan[n], -2.0, 10, 10, 10] <= 100` then

`RegionPlot[1 <= sigma[300, ArcTan[s], ArcTan[n], -2.0, 10, 10, 10] <= 100, {s,0.1, 2}, {n, 1, 10}]`

Gives:

[image]

Comment: Hay any help about solving this equation .. I want at the end to plot `sigma[ms, ArcTan[0.9], ArcTan[0.1], -2.0, 10, zz, 10]` in (ms,zz) plan at the specified region, i.e, `RegionPlot[reg, {ms,100,500},{zz,-10,10}]`, but `Reduce` stuck ..

Answer (score 2):

You are expecting too much of `Reduce` in this case, as `sigma[ms, ArcTan[0.9], ArcTan[0.1], -2.0, 10, zz, 10]` depends on `ms` in a quite complicated way. Therefore you should not expect `Reduce` to be able to give a symbolic rule for when the inequality is satisfied.

However, we can use numerics to try to find approximate regions where the inequalities hold. Since your function is a positive number times an `Abs[]^2` this will always be greater than or equal to zero, so the first inequality is trivially satisfied. Let's then look at how low we may make this function go, without much effort:

```
NMinimize[Evaluate[sigma[ms, ArcTan[0.9], ArcTan[0.1], -2.0, 10, zz, 10]], {ms, zz}]
```

> {1.92359*10^7, {ms -> 0.000012937, zz -> -464232.}}

Oh boy, that is a long way from 10. Plotting around this point indeed gives little hope:

```
Plot3D[sigma[ms, ArcTan[0.9], ArcTan[0.1], -2.0, 10, zz, 10],
{ms, 0, 20}, {zz, -1000000, -100000}, AxesLabel -> {"ms", "zz", ""}]
```

[image: plot]

So unless I'm looking at ridiculous values of `ms, zz` and there is in fact another minimum hidden somwhere, which I doubt, then you won't be able to satisfy your second inequality.

Comment: I want to plot in 2 dimensions  of (ms, zz), and not ContourPlot. Can I use RegionPlot with no need for Reduce ?

Comment: Yes you could have used RegionPlot like this `RegionPlot[0 <= sigma[ms, ArcTan[0.9], ArcTan[0.1], -2.0, 10, zz, 10] <= 10, {ms, ms0, ms1}, {zz, zz0, zz1}]`, but my point is that this will produce an empty plot **no matter what values** of `ms0, ms1, zz0, zz1` you choose, because the `<= 10` inequality is never satisfied for this function.

Comment: `RegionPlot[0 <= sigma[ms, ArcTan[0.9], ArcTan[0.1], -2.0, 10, zz, 10] <= 10, {ms, ms0, ms1}, {zz, zz0, zz1}]`, simply works ..

Comment: @S.S., now I don't follow at all. What do you mean it "simply works"?

Comment: @ Marius Ladegård Meyer , I mean I can guess which ranges of {ms, ms0, ms1}, {zz, zz0, zz1} which can give the region of sigma I acquire in `RegionPlot`, so I considered, it give some thing like the figure I edited in the question, so now `sigma  0 <= sigma[ms, ArcTan[0.9], ArcTan[0.1], -2.0, 10, zz, 10] <= 10`, with no need for `Reduce`.. Many thanks for help .. now I know that `Reduce` can not go through complicated expressions ..

Comment: Are you using some other function than the one in your original post when you made the figure in the edit? What command did you run to create that plot exactly?

Comment: The function plotted is sigma multiplied by other more complicated function, so that I think you notice ranges are may be unexpected or different ..

Comment: See, if that fact is missing from the question then a) this will be really confusing for other people who have a similar problem and find this page looking for answers, and b) it makes my answer wrong and useless. Please add this info to the question, and I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: ok I added `sigma` in the question (it's now * 10 instead of 10^8), and give a real example for it when using `RegionPlot` according to parameters ranges ..